# Absolutely continuous function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

According to Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, a complex-valued function $ f $ on $ [a,b] $ is said to be **absolutely continuous** if $\forall $$\epsilon >0 \ $, $\exists\delta>0\ $  such that 
$$
\sum^n_{k=1}|f(b_k) -f(a_k)|< \epsilon $$

for every $n$ disjoint subintervals $ \ (a_k,b_k) $ of $ \ [a,b] $, $k=1,\cdots,n$, such that
$ \sum^n_{k=1}|b_k -a_k|< \delta $.

Rudin says that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$. Clearly $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$, but how can I show that $f$ is continuous on the endpoints?

Comment: What's the problem with the endpoints? I don't see how the proof of continuity on $[a,b]$ is any different from the proof for $(a,b)$. What goes wrong when you try just using the same argument? You're making an  error or misunderstanding something; can't be more specific until you explain what the problem is...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply obvious that the definition implies continuity on all of $[a,b]$; I can't see what the problem is, because I literally can't think of a proof that $f$ is continuous on $(a,b)$ that doesn't work at the endpoints.

Suppose $\epsilon>0$.  Choose $\delta>0$ as above. Suppose $s,t\in[a,b]$ and $|s-t|<\delta$. Wlog $s<t$. Let $n=1$, $a_1=s$, $b_1=t$. Note that $(a_1,b_1)\subset[a,b]$ and $|b_1-a_1|<\delta$. So the condition above implies $|f(t)-f(s)|=\sum|f(b_j)-f(a_j)|<\epsilon$, qed.

(Yes, I think "obvious" is right...)

Comment: I made a silly comment  earlier. When I saw this answer I upvoted it. It appears that someone later downvoted the answer. I wonder why this was downvoted. I am very glad that David Ulrich pointed out the mistake in comment.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy There's no point to trying to figure out why people downvote things. (If anything it seems to me the OP has some downvotes coming, not for the question _per se_, but for not answering my question about how one gives a proof of continuity on $(a,b)$ that does not work exactly the same for continuity on $[a,b]$...)